# Save mySQL table to array and assign to worksheet - Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have adapted some code I found to extract a mySQL table and write it to a worksheet. However, it is slow for some of the larger tables(30,000+). I am trying to find a better way to import the values and avoid looping. I was hoping to be able to assign it directly to a range, but have been unsuccessful. From my research, it seems Excel is limited when it comes to mySQL. Any suggestions?

```
    Dim password As String
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim dbTable As String
    'OMIT Dim Cn statement
    Dim server_Name As String
    Dim user_ID As String
    Dim database_Name As String
    Dim lRow As Integer, lCol As Integer
    
'Start timer
Dim Count As Long
Dim BenchMark As Double

BenchMark = Timer

    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    'OMIT Dim rs statement
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'EBGen-Daily
    server_Name = Sheet10.Range("b1").Value
    database_Name = Sheet10.Range("b2").Value ' Name of database
    user_ID = Sheet10.Range("b3").Value 'id user or username
    password = Sheet10.Range("b4").Value 'Password
    dbTable = Sheet10.Range("tbl_name").Value

    sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " & dbTable

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
'On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=" & server_Name & ";" & _
        "DATABASE=" & database_Name & ";" & _
        "USER=" & user_ID & ";" & _
        "PASSWORD=" & password & ";" & _
        "Option=16427"

    rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adOpenStatic
    
    'MsgBox cn.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) As row_count FROM elite_advocacy;")!row_count + 1

    Dim myArray()

    myArray = rs.GetRows()

    kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1)
    rader = UBound(myArray, 2)
    
'Delete existing table
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet2.ListObjects("tbl_data").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'Write array to sheet <<< Slow for large datasets
    For k = 0 To kolumner ' Using For loop data are displayed
        Sheet2.Range("rng_s_data").Offset(0, k).Value = rs.Fields(k).Name
        For r = 0 To rader
           Sheet2.Range("rng_s_data").Offset(r + 1, k).Value = myArray(k, r)
        Next
    Next
    
'Write array to range <<< Failed

'Attempt 2
'Dim r1 As Range, rBase As Range
'Dim L As Long, U As Long
'Set rBase = Sheet2.Range("rng_s_data")
'L = LBound(myArray)
'U = UBound(myArray)

'r1 = rBase.Resize(1, rader - kolumner + 1)
'r1 = myArray
    
    
    
'Find lRow and lCol
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Range("rng_s_data").Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = Cells(Range("rng_s_data").Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
'Create a table from Data
    'Sheet2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet2.Range("A$5:$Z$100"), , xlYes).Name = "tbl_data"
    Sheet2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Range("rng_s_data").Row, Sheet2.Range("rng_s_data").Column), _
        Sheet2.Cells(lRow, lCol)), , xlYes).Name = "tbl_data"
    Sheet2.ListObjects("tbl_data").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
    
'Autofit Sheet
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

'End Timer
MsgBox Timer - BenchMark
Errorhandler:
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have mySQl for testing, but something like this would be a generic approach to querying any database from Excel using ADO.

Performance is optimum if you avoid any looping which involves cell-by-cell access, and do as much as you can with arrays, before transferring the final array to the worksheet in a single operation.

It's worth putting in extra effort to create re-usable pieces of code as standalone Subs or Functions - that allows your main logic to stay focused on the task at hand.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String, dbTable As String, data, rngTbl As Range
    Dim BenchMark As Double

    BenchMark = Timer

    Set cn = GetConnection()
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    dbTable = Sheet10.Range("tbl_name").Value
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & dbTable
    
    rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic
    
    data = RecordSetToArray(rs)        'Includes field names
    'data = RecordSetToArray(rs,False) 'False = no field names
    
    'Delete existing table
    On Error Resume Next
    sheet2.ListObjects("tbl_data").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'put the data on the worksheet
    Set rngTbl = ArrayToSheetRange(data, sheet2.Range("rng_s_data"))
    
    With sheet2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTbl, , xlYes)
        .Name = "tbl_data"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
        .Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    Debug.Print "Done in " & Timer - BenchMark

End Sub

'return an opened connection object
Function GetConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim serverNm As String, userId As String, dbNm As String, pw As String
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    serverNm = Sheet10.Range("b1").Value
    dbNm = Sheet10.Range("b2").Value ' Name of database
    userId = Sheet10.Range("b3").Value 'id user or username
    pw = Sheet10.Range("b4").Value 'Password

    cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=" & serverNm & ";" & _
        "DATABASE=" & dbNm & ";" & _
        "USER=" & userId & ";" & _
        "PASSWORD=" & pw & ";" & _
        "Option=16427"
    
    Set GetConnection = cn
End Function

'Create a 2-D array from a recordset
Function RecordSetToArray(rs As ADODB.Recordset, _
                          Optional IncludeFieldNames As Boolean = True)
    Dim tmp, nC As Long, nR As Long, data, r As Long, c As Long, rowNum As Long
    tmp = rs.GetRows()            'cols x rows
    nC = UBound(tmp, 1) + 1       'zero-based --> 1-based
    nR = UBound(tmp, 2) + 1
    ReDim data(1 To nR + IIf(IncludeFieldNames, 1, 0), 1 To nC) 'allow for headers?
    
    If IncludeFieldNames Then
        For c = 1 To nC
            data(1, c) = rs.Fields(c - 1).Name
        Next c
        rowNum = 1
    End If
    For r = 1 To nR
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
        For c = 1 To nC
            data(rowNum, c) = tmp(c - 1, r - 1)
        Next c
    Next r
    RecordSetToArray = data
End Function

'Fill an array to a worksheet starting at `rng`, and return the filled range
Function ArrayToSheetRange(data, rng As Range) As Range
    Dim rv As Range
    Set rv = rng.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2))
    rv.Value = data
    Set ArrayToSheetRange = rv
End Function
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! This works crazy fast (less than 2 seconds to load more ~45,000 rows). My previous code was taking up to a a minute to to perform the same actions.